# Axios get and return corrupted image

Tags: node.js, image, axios, netlify, netlify-function

I like to image proxy API. The API will download an image and return to clients.

However when browsing the API at `http://localhost:8888/api/queue` the image cannot be displayed.

I also tried to use `curl` to write to file:

```bash
curl http://localhost:8888/api/queue --output ./test21.png
```

This still did not work.

Could you please tell me if I have done anything wrong with my code?

```js
router.get("/queue", (req, res) =>  {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/2560px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  }).then(function(response) {
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.write(response.data, 'binary')
    res.end();
    return;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    res.send("error:" + error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your API lives in /queue, but you were trying to access /api/queue, or was it a router? anyway, the code works fine on my end.

Comment: yes. it's router. "api.use("/api/", router);".

Comment: This code works fine on my end, what error did you see?

Comment: The root cause should be setting up api on Netlify. When I changed and run on express it works.